# Header with chapter title

Tags: header-footer

I would like to have a header in my thesis looking like the one in the picture below. I have everything except the chapter title besides the vertical bar. How can I manage that? My document class is report and I'm working with a two sided document. (See code example)

Thank you alot for your help. [image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RequirePackage[times]{quotchap}
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                               
\pagestyle{fancy}

\def\layout{2}  

\ifnum\layout=2 
    \fancyhf{}      
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\chaptername~ \thechapter~ |}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{ \rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{         
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}    
 \else          
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}                  
    \fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fi

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{subsection}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? It seems that package are missing to make your code work.

Comment: I'm sorry. It should work now.

Comment: Is an answer acceptable  for you? Please accept an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *very* simple with `titleps`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RequirePackage[times]{quotchap}
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mine}{
\sethead[\chaptername~ \thechapter~|~\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\thesection.~\sectiontitle}
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{subsection}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems like adding `\leftmark` would give your desired output:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RequirePackage[times]{quotchap}
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                               
\pagestyle{fancy}

\def\layout{2}  

\ifnum\layout=2 
    \fancyhf{}      
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\chaptername~ \thechapter~ |~ \leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{ \rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{         
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}    
 \else          
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}                  
    \fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fi

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{subsection}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]